# Make C Project Instead of C++

Tags: c++, c, clion

I am having trouble setting up a C projectin Clion. I changed the name of the main.cpp to main.c, and altered the CMakeLists file accordingly, with the following info:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Project_1__)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(Project_1__ ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

However I get the following error when I try to build:

> fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory  #include  compilation terminated. mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Project_1__.dir/main.c.obj] Error 1 mingw32-make.exe[2]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles/Project_1__.dir/all] Error 2

Comment: Can you show us main.c? It seems like it still contains a line like this `#include <iostream>` which isn't C

Comment: Are you saying you tried to change the source language of your project without editing the source files? (C and C++ are different languages.) That doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to fact that your **complier is unable to find iostream header file**. Make sure it exists in that directory. Plus it also depends on your *IDE*.

Also make sure, it is declared as `#include "iostream.h"` instead of `#include<iostream.h>`

**iostream** header files are declared in many of the compilers is declared by `#include<iostream>`

*C++* needs `<iostream>` header file while *C* needs only `<stdio.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#include <iostream>` with `#include <stdio.h>`.  You'll also have to replace the stream related stuff in your code with stdio functions.  See `man stdio`.

Also, you may have to change your makefile as I see `-std=c++11` and I suspect that should be `-std=c11`.  I'm not completely clear on this, so YMMV

Answer (score 0):

`iostream.h` is specific to c++, c do not use stream classes